# 周礼 passage on youth education

Tags: classical-chinese, dictionary

There is a following passage in 说文解字:

《周禮》：八歲入小學，保氏教國子，先以六書。一曰指事。指事者，視而可識，察而見意，「上、下」是也。二曰象形。象形者，畫成其物，隨體詰詘，「日、月」是也。三曰形聲。形聲者，以事為名，取譬相成，「江、河」是也。四曰會意。會意者，比類合誼，以見指撝，「武、信」是也。五曰轉注。轉注者，建類一首，同意相受，「考、老」是也。六曰假借。假借者，本無其事，依聲託事，「令、長」是也。

I was trying to locate the reference in 周礼 but I could not find it. Any ideas where is it from exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . . . 所說的「周禮」，並非書名專稱的《周禮》，而是泛指周代的禮教制度而言。

in the preface of “說文解字”, the term “周禮” used by mr 許, is **not** refer to the book “周禮”; that, it should read as the rite system (禮教制度) of the 周 dynasty.

https://www.books.com.tw/web/sys_serialtext/?item=0010870575&page=4

have fun :)